# Insert image into a framebuffer and write framebuffer to png

Tags: python, png, framebuffer, pyglet

I'm new to Python and have been working full time on learning the language. I would like to be able to:

- read a `png` into the video framebuffer and display it in a window
- read-modify-write a single pixel
- write the video framebuffer back into a `png`

Seems simple enough and I've been able to do parts using [pyglet](/questions/tagged/pyglet). I've read hundreds of documents and it seems I'm getting more confused.

Could someone point in the right direction?

Comment: Could you show us, specifically, what exactly you're having trouble with?

Comment: I modified the title, I hope this is more towards what you were asking.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24226695/edit) to add more details as the comments system is not designed for this.

Comment: The following allows me load a png, read a pixel but this is as far as I got   <br/>'import png
import pyglet

# use png
p = [(255,128,0, 0,255,0, 0,0,255),
     (128,0,0, 0,128,0, 0,0,128)]
f = open('swatch.png', 'wb')
w = png.Writer(3, 2)
w.write(f, p) 
f.close()
window = pyglet.window.Window()
image = pyglet.resource.image('swatch.png')
y=1
x=0
pix = image.get_region(x,y,1,1).get_image_data().get_data("RGB", 3)
R1 = ord(pix[0])
G1 = ord(pix[1])
B1 = ord(pix[2])
print  x, R1, G1, B1

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()    
    image.blit(0,0)


pyglet.app.run()'

Answer (score 0):

as a first hint, I'dcheck those functions :

- to capture a video frame : `pyglet.image.get_texture()`
  (doc here : http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.media.Player-class.html )
- to save a png : `pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save(filename)`
- to play with pixels, as you are working with a texture, the `pyglet.image.ImageData` class should be the pyglet class to look at.
  (doc of the API here : http://pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.image.ImageData-class.html#format)